# Update fb_app_id in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I used my developer fb_app_id for facebook login via cordova plugin. It is working fine. Now I want to update fb_app_id to production app id. Where should I update it. I am using Ionic V1 for development.

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the **developer fb_app_id** with the **production app id** . You might have written the developer fb_app_id in your code somewhere, you just need to replace it, it should work.

And more over, try to get the fb_app_id from a webservice and use it in your app so that you don't need to rebuild the app whenever you want a shift from develop to production. You will have to rebuild the app if you have hardcoded the app id in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed APP_ID value in android.json and ios.json under plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin. Then I rebuild the application and it updated the fb_app_id.